# In Romans 5:6 Did Jesus die for the Ungodly or for the Righteous (Godly) Sinners?

Tags: jesus, romans, sacrifice

Romans 5:6 (ASV):

> 6. For while we were yet weak, in due season Christ died **for the ungodly.**

Did Jesus die on the cross to redeem the Righteous (Godly) Sinners, or to redeem all humanity, including the Ungodly Sinners?

I mean, since there are a sin unto death and a sin not  unto death, and there are a good conscience and a weak conscience, So there are Righteous Sinners (sinners with good conscience) and Ungodly Sinners (sinners with weak conscience).

I hope you understand what I am saying.

The term (good conscience) is Biblical, look: Acts 23:1 and 1 Timothy 1:5.

The term (weak conscience) is Biblical, look: 1 Corinthians 8:10, 12.

So, Did Jesus Christ suffer on the cross for all Humanity?, Including pious and impious, godly and ungodly?

I hope you understand my words.

Comment: Limited or unlimited atonement is a massive subject that should be asked about at the [christianity.se] site instead. But I don't think "righteous sinners" is a concept Paul would recognise. Where else do you see that in Romans?

Comment: @curiousdannii the post is very Hermeneutic, I hope you try to give answer here.

Comment: "Righteous sinner" is a contradiction.  This term is unbiblical!!

Comment: @Dottard hermenutically you can infer it. The righteous sinner has good conscience inspite of being sinner, i.e: the problem is not in his conscience.

Comment: That is still an unbiblical idea.

Comment: Everyone has a conscience.  And having a conscience is no insurance of righteousness, you can (and do) violate your conscience.  If you don't think you violate your conscience, that's called self righteousness.  And whenever you sin, and violate your own conscience, you experience guilt.  There is no such thing as "good conscience".  Conscience is conscience, it convicts you of your sin, and while that is a good thing, it never feels good.  It feels horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Romans 5:6 means exactly what it says: "Christ … died on behalf of the ungodly."

The word "ungodly" here is ἀσεβής (asebés).

Thayer defines this word as

> ἀσεβής, ἐς (σέβω to reverence); from Aeschylus and Thucydides down,
>   the Sept. for רָשָׁע ; destitute of reverential awe toward God,
>   contemning God, impious: Romans 4:5; Romans 5:6; 1 Timothy 1:9 (joined
>   here with ἁμαρτωλός, as in 1 Peter 4:18); 2 Peter 2:5; 2 Peter 3:7;
>   Jude 1:4, 15.

Strong's gives the following meaning:

> ungodly man. From a (as a negative particle) and a presumed derivative
>   of sebomai; irreverent, i.e. (by extension) impious or wicked --
>   ungodly (man).

The word occurs 9 times in the NT: Rom 4:5, 5:6, 1 Tim 1:9, 1 Peter 4:18, 2 Peter 2:5, 6, 3:7, Jude 4, 15 and denotes sinners who have no inclination to God or who are opposed to God.

BDAG defines the word as:

> pertaining to violating norms for a proper relation to deity,
>   *irreverent, impious, ungodly*.

The idea presented in Rom 5:6 is common in the NT as follows:

- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw all people to myself.”
- Acts 17:30, “God … commands all people everywhere to repent.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for all have sinned … and all are freely forgiven...”
- Rom 5:8, 10, “… while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. … if, while were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him by the death of His Son, …”
- Rom 5:15, “But the free gift is not like the offense. For if by the one man’s [Adam’s] offense many died, much more the grace of God and the gift by the grace of the one Man, Jesus Christ, abounded to the many.”  [Note the same word, “many” applies to all people.]
- Rom 5:18, “Therefore, as through one man’s offense judgment came to all people, resulting in condemnation, even so through one Man’s righteous act the free gift came to all people, resulting in justification of life.”
- Rom 11:32, “For God has imprisoned everyone in disobedience so that He may show mercy to all.”
- 2 Cor 5:14, “…we are convinced that one died for all, and therefore all died.”
- 2 Cor 5:18, 19, “…God was reconciling the world to Himself in Christ …”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”
- Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
- Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honour because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”
- 2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.”
- 1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for the whole world.”
- Isa 53:6, “We all like sheep have gone astray … and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all.”

That is, Christ died for all, this includes those who will later be saved and those who will not.  See Rom 5 extended discussion by Paul (partially quoted above).  The same words are used for all that sinned and all that are justified.  This is not to suggest that all will be saved because some reject Jesus offer of salvation, and there are numerous examples of this in the Scripture.  But I will not list them here.

Comment: thus, you adopt (Jesus died on the cross for all Humanity)?. This also my point of view.

Comment: your answer will be perfect if you write conclusion including your opinion.

Comment: I need you to write explicitly that He died also for the Ungodly, to give you the best answer.

Comment: I do not need to write that because Paul wrote that Jesus died for the ungodly and I completely agree.

Comment: I already choose your answer as the best.

Answer (score 2):

there is no distinction...all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, being justified freely by His grace through the redemption which is in Christ Jesus...demonstrating...His righteousness in the present time, so that He might be righteous and the One who justifies him who is of the faith of Jesus...the law of faith. For we account that a man is justified by faith apart from the works of the law......
Behold, the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world!

If anyone sees his brother sinning a sin not unto death, he shall ask and he will give life to him, to those sinning not unto death. There is a sin unto death; I do not say that he should make request concerning that. All unrighteousness is sin, and there is sin not unto death.

1 Jn 5:16-17 has nothing to do with a fantasy of "righteous vs ungodly sinners." Rather 16-17 concerns children of God, in His assembly, God's discipline of His own, born-anew, family (cf 1 Pet 4:17; 1 Cor 11:30).

Our conscience is deep. In our spirit. Our deepest part. Rm 9:1; 8:16; 1:9; Zech 12:1; 1 Thes 5:23. It's also in our heart. Heb 10:22. Unbelievers' spirits are dead (Eph 2:1; Gen 2:17), void of God. Though the conscience...still can function. Rm 2:14-15; cf Gen 3:7. The only way to know God is to receive God, because God is receivable. He's the Spirit and He became the life-giving Spirit. The way to receive Christ is to meet Him personally.

For when Gentiles, who have no law, do by nature the things of the law, these, though they have no law, are a law to themselves, who show the work of the law written in their hearts, their conscience bearing witness with it and their reasonings, one with the other, accusing or even excusing them.)

The true worshippers will worship the Father in spirit and truthfulness, for the Father also seeks such to worship Him. God is Spirit, and those who worship Him must worship in spirit and truthfulness. The woman said to Him, I know that Messiah is coming (He who is called Christ); when He comes, He will declare all things to us. Jesus said to her, I, who speak to you, am He.

Regeneration (Jn 1:10-12; 3:16) enlivens Christians' consciences Ac 23:1; 1 Tim 1:5; 1 Cor 8:10, 12. A weak conscience isn't a bad one, but is one overly-sensitive or without sufficient faith/knowledge. Believers should protect, be gentle with, one anothers' conscience. All consciences.